# LINQ provider- mapping an object through an array indexer?

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a class, LanguageModeration. It contains booleans for a number of languages, showing whether they have been moderated or not. I have implemented an indexer, allowing me to select by an Enum I've named Language. Like so:

```
public class LanguageModeration
{
    public ModerationRecord EN {get;set;}
    public ModerationRecord FR {get;set;}
}

public ModerationRecord  this[Language l]
{
    get
    {
        if (l == Language.English) return EN;
        else return FR;
    }
}
```

I'd like to use this syntax (or something similar) in an NHibernate LINQ expression, something like:

```
from m in _exampleLanguageModerationList where m[Language.English] == false select m
```

That doesn't work, I get this:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Dm.Mvc.Data.SiteObjects.ModerationRecord get_Item(Dm.Mvc.Data.Types.Language)
```

Is it even possible to do what I want with NHibernate LINQ right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing `m[Language.English]` against a `bool`.

Since you're returning EN or FR.. shouldn't the return type of your indexer be `bool`?

Comment: Just changed it, thanks. It's because I've stripped the example code down from my actual code to highlight the core issue.

Comment: Ok, this should work as expected... What is the exact error you get from the compiler?  Also, what type is `_exampleLanguageModerationList`?  `IQueryable` should not be required to get this to work.

Comment: OK, my idiocy at work here. I'm using this with an NHibernate LINQ provider, and the error is actually occurring within that provider, not with LINQ. Apologies- I guess I'll flag this for deletion.